# How to save dataframe (csv or whatever) with changed type of variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I read a csv file into the console, look at the type of variables via str(data), change some vars to the required types (factor, integer, numeric, etc.) and after that I want to **save(write) this file back to the PC with these changes - that´s problem.

Is there any way how to save file with these changes ???**

```
#reading csv to console
mydata= read.csv("mydata.csv" , header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".")

#looking at types
str(mydata)

#changing type of variable - first column calls variable1 and it is integer, I want factor
mydata$variable1 = as.factor(as.character(mydata$variable1))

#looking at types again, mydata$variable1 is factor right now
str(mydata)

#writing that file in PC, with changes
write.csv(mydata, file = "converted_mydata.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

and now when I read this csv there is no change - mydata$variable1 is again integer.

```
#reading csv to console
mydata_changed= read.csv("converted_mydata.csv" , header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the more info about the data and the desired output. You can do so by providing the output of dput(head(mydata)) and then explain what would you like to see in your output file.

Comment: Data types aren't encoded in csv files. If you look at the csv file, it's just text. If you need to keep data types, you can use `saveRDS`

Comment: @camille yea, that´s what i am looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish should work when you explicitly specify factor labels, for example like this:

```
mydata$variable1 = factor(mydata$variable1, labels = c("label1", "label2", ... ))
```

The number of labels and what name you use of course depends on the nature of your variable "variable1".

Note that this way the data type factor is not stored in the csv file itself, but the function `read.csv` will restore it as factor (this is because by default it reads string values as factors).